# Ansible: TypeError: 'timeout' object does not support indexing

Tags: ansible

I am running Ansible for VMware, I have two vCenters and some tasks, but one task is failing in one vCenter only. I am using the same Ansible server, same permissions and same username, running Ansible version 2.9.27, python 2.7.5 and VMware SDK, both vCenter/ESXi has the same version, and access, so I don't know why just one task is failing in  one vCenter this is the task:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vsphere_file_module.html

```yaml
- name: Create directories on local datastore
  community.vmware.vsphere_file:
    host: "{{ vcenter_server }}"
    username: "{{ provider.user }}"
    password: "{{ provider.password }}"
    validate_certs:  "{{ provider.validate_certs }}"
    #esxi_hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
    datastore: "{{ local_log_datastore_prefix }}"
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    loop: "{{ esxi_local_datastore_folders }}"
```

This is the error :

```
    <localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
    <localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
    <localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748234.07-77454-176593688580855 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1657748234.07-77454-176593688580855="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748234.07-77454-176593688580855 `" ) && sleep 0'
    Using module file /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vsphere_file.py
    <localhost> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-774132iPz96/tmpUa3kiC TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748234.07-77454-176593688580855/AnsiballZ_vsphere_file.py
    <localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748234.07-77454-176593688580855/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748234.07-77454-176593688580855/AnsiballZ_vsphere_file.py && sleep 0'
    <localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748234.07-77454-176593688580855/AnsiballZ_vsphere_file.py && sleep 0'
    <localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748234.07-77454-176593688580855/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
    The full traceback is:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_38e7eivm/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vsphere_file.py", line 194, in main
      File "/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_38e7eivm/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 1390, in open_url
      File "/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_38e7eivm/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 1294, in open
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_38e7eivm/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 467, in https_open
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1352, in do_open
        r = h.getresponse()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1346, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 268, in _read_status
        line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 971, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 833, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 590, in read
        v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748244.8-77454-4966237197380/AnsiballZ_vsphere_file.py", line 102, in <module>
        _ansiballz_main()
      File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748244.8-77454-4966237197380/AnsiballZ_vsphere_file.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
        invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
      File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748244.8-77454-4966237197380/AnsiballZ_vsphere_file.py", line 40, in invoke_module
        runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.vmware.plugins.modules.vsphere_file', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
        return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
        mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_ds9zbmfy/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vsphere_file.py", line 349, in <module>
      File "/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_ds9zbmfy/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vsphere_file.py", line 198, in main
    TypeError: 'timeout' object does not support indexing
    failed: [server01.loc -> localhost] (item=.locker-server01.loc) => {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "changed": false,
        "item": ".locker-server01.loc",
        "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_ds9zbmfy/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vsphere_file.py\", line 194, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_ds9zbmfy/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py\", line 1390, in open_url\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_ds9zbmfy/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py\", line 1294, in open\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py\", line 223, in urlopen\n    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py\", line 526, in open\n    response = self._open(req, data)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py\", line 544, in _open\n    '_open', req)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py\", line 504, in _call_chain\n    result = func(*args)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_ds9zbmfy/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py\", line 467, in https_open\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py\", line 1352, in do_open\n    r = h.getresponse()\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py\", line 1346, in getresponse\n    response.begin()\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py\", line 307, in begin\n    version, status, reason = self._read_status()\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py\", line 268, in _read_status\n    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), \"iso-8859-1\")\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py\", line 586, in readinto\n    return self._sock.recv_into(b)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py\", line 971, in recv_into\n    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py\", line 833, in read\n    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py\", line 590, in read\n    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)\nsocket.timeout: The read operation timed out\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748244.8-77454-4966237197380/AnsiballZ_vsphere_file.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748244.8-77454-4966237197380/AnsiballZ_vsphere_file.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1657748244.8-77454-4966237197380/AnsiballZ_vsphere_file.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.vmware.plugins.modules.vsphere_file', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_ds9zbmfy/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vsphere_file.py\", line 349, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload_ds9zbmfy/ansible_community.vmware.vsphere_file_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vsphere_file.py\", line 198, in main\nTypeError: 'timeout' object does not support indexing\n",
        "module_stdout": "",
        "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
        "rc": 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I don't know why just one task is failing in one vCenter*

You get the error mostly because of a connection problem.

```
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
...
      File "... ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 467, in https_open
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1352, in do_open
        r = h.getresponse()
...
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 833, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 590, in read
        v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

The request is timing out or do not get data. You will need to find out why.

Than, because it is not possible to establish the communication fully and you get an error message, you get the next error.

```
TypeError: 'timeout' object does not support indexing
```

Which means just, it isn't possible to index the error message to anything meaningful for further processing within the module. That error, the last one comes from Python and has therefore not much to do with Ansible itself, apart from that Ansible and the modules are written in Python.

**Further References**

- [TypeError: object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128514/)
- [TypeError : object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352235/)
- [Python: Object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463866/)
- [Object Does Not Support Indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978738/)
- [Python: TypeError: object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865252/)

Comment: Thanks so much, you gave me a clue, I added a timeout value in the task, and now is working seems that the task takes more time that's why  I had that timeout error